# VBA select column that matches value and copy data to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel workbooks, **rh** and **summary**. I have code in the **summary** that checks the **rh** file to find a specific column based on the text within it. I need to find these columns, copy them and send the data to the summary sheet.

```
Sub Main()

' Declare hr workbook file
Dim rh As Excel.Workbook

' initialise hr workbook file
Set rh = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\AC74338\Desktop\ac\rh")

'select the rh file
rh.Select

'select the open worksheet
Sheets("Open").Select

' search for the column header that matches e.g. "Org Level 6"
OrgLevel6 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Org Level 6", Rows("1:1"), 0)
OrgLevel7 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Org Level 7", Rows("1:1"), 0)

'activate this workbook where the code is
ThisWorkbook.Activate

'paste the data that was copied to this workbook in the NxNOpen worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NxNOpen").Columns(OrgLevel6).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NxNOpen").Columns(OrgLevel7).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")

End Sub
```

I have debugged and get an error when assigning the data to the OrgLevel6 variable. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? not very knowledgeable with VB so may be a simple mistake.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using a `WorksheetFunction` in VBA you need to still use VBA `Range` references so instead of using `Rows(1:1)` you'll need to refer to the row in VBA code. For example:

```
OrgLevel6 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Org Level 6", rh.Sheets("Open").Rows(1), 0)
OrgLevel7 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Org Level 7", rh.Sheets("Open").Rows(1), 0)
```

Comment: added your edits to the code, the Org Level 6 column is in column K but it is copying column AD, any suggestion why?

Comment: Well you've got `Sheets("Open")` in the `Match` function but then you're actually copying from `Sheets("NxNOpen")` - if you make these consistent you will be copying from the same `Sheet` as you're using to match.

Comment: Brilliant help, i was referencing the wrong sheet, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Change `Rows("1:1")` to `Rows(1)`.

You are applying the Match function on the worksheet named "Open", but you are copying the data from sheet "NxNOpen". Right column, wrong sheet

Comment: cheers, any possible answer to why it would not match the correct column header containing Org Level 6?

Comment: Yes.  You are applying the Match function on the worksheet named "Open", but you are copying the data from sheet "NxNOpen".  Right column, wrong sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your `OrgLevel6 =` line and it works fine with one sheet, so it's possible that it's executing without the correct sheet active and as a result is unable to find "Org Level 6".

Try changing `Sheets("Open").Select` to `Sheets("Open").Activate`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
Sub Main()

' Declare hr workbook file
Dim rh As Excel.Workbook
Dim sum As Excel.Workbook

Dim b As Integer

' initialise hr workbook file
Set rh = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\AC74338\Desktop\ac\rh")
Set sum = ThisWorkbook


b = 1

lcol = rh.Sheets("Open").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To lcol

If rh.Sheets("Open").Cells(1, i).Value = "Org Level 6" Or "Org Level 7" Then

rh.Sheets("Open").Columns(i).Copy sum.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, b)
b = b + 1

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jordan solved the problem in regards to the error i was getting, thanks for this i will implement this as it allows me to select the multiple columns easily.

Comment: No Problem. Cheers